# The application "TorBrowser" can't be opened

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I opened up Tor, and was told that my browser was outdated.  I downloaded the new version and copied over the original.  Now I receive this very vague error: (See screenshot.)

> The application "TorBrowser" can't be opened.

I've reinstalled, rebooted, checked sys prefs to allow for execution of any app, etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you start the Tor Browser from the terminal and see what the (Tor-specific) logs say? If there are no logs output, try passing the `-v` flag. (The problem _could_ be something to do with permissions.)

Comment: Were you logged in as a different user when you copied the new version over the old one?

Comment: I cannot contribute to other possible scenarios, but there's my take on the issue. Had this very same problem, but then I started to look up on absolutely unrelated (or so I thought) old familiar thing what I had years ago - it was issue about more than one system group having same Primary Group ID. I changed them to values I had before by means of Directory Editor (inside of Directory Utility) and then later by pure coincidence (I was not doing group ID rearranging by any relation to this problem) I discovered that TorBrowser opened just fine. Problem was gone! Remember one thing though - do

Comment: Another OSX user affected by this issue. 1. Right mouse (context) launch in Applications produces "The application "TorBrowser" can't be opened." FAIL.
2. sudo open /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
Produces the "Can't launch because TorBrowser is from unidentified developer" FAIL.
3. Installing TorBrowser to local user (~/Applications) folder and right mouse launch successfully launched app. SUCCESS. Agree with other posters this is probably a group permissions error. This issue needs to be drawn to package maintainer's attention: requiring obscure installation/launch proced

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can open it with the following in the terminal: `open /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`

Comment: This worked but I had to run via `sudo` for anyone else having this issue.  Is there a way to resolve this permanently?  Should I inform the Tor team?  If so how do I collect the logs while reproducing the issue since I can only repro the issue by double clicking the app icon?

Answer (score 1):

Put the TorBrowser.app into your /Users/xxxx/Applications folder and it should work fine.  This will be easier than messing with the Group ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Torbrowser without sudo (running a web browser as root is a bad idea), but you have to invoke it explicitly:

```
cd /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS
./firefox
```